# jQuery Validate plugin not working for phone number

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that needs to validate both US and UK phone numbers(preferably based on what the user selects from the dropdown menu next to the input. I have the following form code:

```
<form id="phone">
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center;">
         <h5>Get a link on your phone</h5> 
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="label" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">+1 <span class="caret"></span>

                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" id="1">US: +1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="44">UK: +44</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control phone" id="phone" name="phone" aria-label="..." placeholder="Your phone number" type="text"> <span class="input-group-btn">
              <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
              </span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and corresponding jQuery:

```
$('#phone').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var phone = $(this).find('.phone').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/textMessage/' + phone,
    method: "GET",
    success: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
});

});

$("#1, #44").click(function (e) {
    $("#label").html("+" + $(this).attr("id") + " <span class='caret'></span>");
});
$('.phone').on('input', function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});

$("#phone").validate({
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        }
    }
});
```

I can't get the validation to work, and not sure how to use it for UK numbers either.

Comment: To use the `phoneUS` and `phoneUK` rules, you must include [the plugin's  `addtional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js).

Answer (score 0):

This is more like what you should be doing.  (Note how your `ajax()` belongs inside of the `submitHandler`.)

```
$("#phone").validate({
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true  // start with the default
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/textMessage/' + $('input[name="phone"]').val(),
            method: "GET",
            success: function () {
                console.log(form);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

You cannot apply `phoneUS` and `phoneUK` to the same field at the same time since the two `regex` methods conflict with each other. US phone numbers will be invalid when they're being evaluated for the `phoneUK` rule.

The solution must be a bit more complicated by using *dynamic* rule swapping with the `.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` methods.

```
var phone = $('input[name="phone"]');

if ($(this).attr("id") == '1') {
    phone.rules('remove', 'phoneUK');
    phone.rules('add', {
        phoneUS: true
    });
} else {
    phone.rules('remove', 'phoneUS');
    phone.rules('add', {
        phoneUK: true
    });
}
```

*(Note, I tried "chaining" the methods to reduce the number of lines but the plugin does not allow `.rules()` to be chained to `.rules()`.)*

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/1a8r5gmv/21/**

---

Fix your broken layout by placing the error message using the `errorPlacement` option.  By default, it's inserted immediately after the `input` element.  Apparently, you need it outside of the element's parent `div`.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter($(element).parent('div'));
},
```

Also, customize the messages with the `messages` option.

```
messages: {
    phone: {
        phoneUS: "enter valid US number",
        phoneUK: "enter valid UK number"
    }
},
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/1a8r5gmv/22/**

---

**NOTES**:

Invalid HTML here:  `<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>`

You are closing an `<input>` tag with a `</button>` tag.

Should be...

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

OR

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
```

---

Also, in your OP (not in the jsFiddle) you use `id="phone"` on the `<form>` element as well as the `<input>` element.  You cannot duplicate any `id` on a page.

---

You should not do this...

```
$(this).find('.phone').val()
```

The `class` `phone` could be more than one element so you should not attach `.val()` to a group of elements when you want to get the value of one element.  Also, when moving this inside of the `submitHandler`, the `$(this)` object becomes meaningless.  Simply get the value of the field directly.

```
$('input[name="phone"]').val()
```

Comment: that logic works, but when the ajax call is in the submit handler, it fails to fire.

Comment: Something is still blocking the ajax call from going through: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/1a8r5gmv/24/

Comment: @Matt, you cannot use `ajax()` in a jsFiddle because the URL is pointing to jsFiddle and not your own server-side code.  That's why I commented it out and used an `alert()` for the demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/1a8r5gmv/25/

Comment: I know you can't make an ajax call like that. I was referring to my own project. It's not hitting the success call(which is where I would see the console log message).

Comment: @Matt, put the `error` callback into your `ajax()` and inspect what it returns.  Also, try the `complete` callback to verify that it completes.  See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/